# Converting multiple strings into one then parsing to int

Tags: java, string, parseint, typecast-operator

I know this is not the simplest way to find a palindrome...but I was hoping someone might tell me if there is a way to convert multiple strings of integers into a single int. Maybe that builds a single string from others? Below I have an output that reverses the number you input. However, it comes out as a string of separate integers. Would I be able to typecast this into a single int then bool it against the original number somehow?
If I overlooked a topic similar to this, I'm sorry. I checked around and didn't find one that clearly solved my issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrone{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter an integer between 2 and 6 digits:");
  int num1 = input.nextInt();

  int rev = 0;
  //find last number
  if(num1 >= 10){
    rev = num1%10;
    System.out.print(rev);
  }
  //find 2nd to last and 3rd from last
  if(num1 >= 100){
    rev = num1%100/10;
    System.out.print(rev);
    rev = num1%1000/100;
    System.out.print(rev);
  }
  //find 4th from last
  if(num1 >= 1000){
    rev = num1%10000/1000;
    System.out.print(rev);
  }
  //find 5th
  if(num1 >= 10000){
    rev = num1%100000/10000;
    System.out.print(rev);
  }
  //find 6th
  if(num1 >= 100000){
    rev = num1%1000000/100000;
    System.out.print(rev);
  } 
 }      
}
```

I'm trying to go from printing string (int rev)(int rev)(int rev)(int rev) to 
one solid string then converting to int. Then if(newInt == num1) run statement.

Comment: If looking for palindrome itd prolly be best to read in as a String. This would let you do any sized "number" up to the String max size.But if you want to go this way, you can have a `String backwardsNum` and then concatenate the strings. so `backwardsNum += /*Whatever goes here*/`

Comment: Very much agree with Michael Pickett about the best way to find a palendrome. As to your question about multiple strings of ints into an int... you need to be more clear about what you want. Please provide at least a sample input and what you would expect the output to be. As stated, this is confusing.

Comment: Beware `0` digits. You seem to be trying to reverse a number, but the reverse of `10` is `1`, not `01`. If you want the result to remember leading zeroes (from trailing zeroes of input), you really need to do it as string, not as number.

Comment: Thank you Michael Pickett. I will try that.

Comment: nhouser19 - I guess the best way to show what I'm trying to do is go from: String output (rev# rev# rev# rev#) which is 4 separate strings on the same line. To: String output (rev####) as one string then convert that to an int so I can bool it against num1. Thank you for your help, I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Andreas - dangit you are right. Thank you.  I will have to address that later. At this point I'm really just trying to see how to take multiple string outputs from the same line and convert to one string. It's looking like concatenating will be the way to go though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go this way without the headache of string-int conversion:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer between 2 and 6 digits: ");
String number = input.next();        
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(number).reverse()); //prints reverse number
```

Comment: You technically don't need `toString()` in a `println()` call. `println(Object)` will call `toString()` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, the following method uses Guava to perform the various steps:

```
public static boolean palindrome(int number) {
    // Split into an array of digits and reverse
    List<String> digits = Lists.transform(
            Lists.reverse(
                    Lists.transform(
                            Lists.transform(
                                    Lists.charactersOf(Integer.toString(number)),
                                    Functions.toStringFunction()),
                            Ints.stringConverter())),
            Ints.stringConverter().reverse());

    // Join the strings and parse to an integer
    int result = Integer.parseInt(Joiner.on("").join(digits));

    // And check if a palindrome
    return (result == number);
}
```

So, you could use the same technique with your code, if you create an empty list at the beginning, and add each parsed integer to the end of the list. However the way you are using the modulus operator with the fixed sequence of numbers multiplying by 10 each time is limiting. Instead, if you want to use this parsing method, consider a loop instead:

```
List<Integer> digits = Lists.newArrayList();
while (number > 10) {
    int digit = number % 10;
    digits.add(digit);
    number /= 10;
}
```

Then reverse and transform back to a list of strings, and convert to an integer:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.transform(
        Lists.reverse(digits),
        Ints.stringConverter().reverse());
int result = Integer.parseInt(Joiner.on("").join(strings));
```

And again just check for equality with the original number.